# Image animation works, but text animation doesn't

Tags: html, css, css-animations

My image animation works fine, but text animation doesn't work at all. Where I am going wrong with this code?

```css
@-webkit-keyframes hue {
  from {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes round {
  100% {
    border-radius: 0px;
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
    opacity: 100%;
  }
  0% {
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    opacity: 0%;
  }
}

img {
  animation: round 3s ease-in-out;
}

#anim {
  -webkit-animation: hue 60s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<h1>As you see this animation works fine:</h1>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwSTv.png?s=328&g=1">
<hr>
<h1 class="anim">But this text must be animated with hue animation!</h1>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bwp1n56v/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - as RussAwesome mentioned - you are using an ID selector instead of  class selector.

Second - try setting the text color to a different value than black.
For example: Red

```
.anim {
   color:red;
   -webkit-animation: hue 2s infinite linear;
 }
```

Here's your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bwp1n56v/8/)

I've reduced the animation time to better show the effect.

Answer (score 2):

You have set the HTML to have `class="anim"` but you have declared the CSS with an id instead: `#anim {...}` Change this to `.anim` or change your HTML to be `id="anim"`

Comment: Thanks very much! All time before your answer I was thinking # is class and . is id. :D But actually # is id and . is class.

Comment: Wait... I replaced **class="anim"** with **id="anim"** but it still not works :( https://jsfiddle.net/bwp1n56v/6/

Comment: It is actually working. But the black color of your h1  is not affected by the hue...